# Using scrollifys interstitialSection for a footer

Tags: jquery, footer, jquery-scrollify

Can you help with implementing a footer with scrollify please. From the instructions on the website http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/ i believe that all that I need to do is declare my footer as a interstitialSection. But though this takes the footer out of the panels/slides I cant scroll to it with the mouse.

```
$(function() {
  $.scrollify({
      section : ".panel",
    interstitialSection : ".footer",
      easing: "easeOutExpo",
      scrollSpeed: 800,
      offset : 0,
      scrollbars: true,
      standardScrollElements: "",
      before:function() {},
      after:function() {},
      afterResize:function() {},
      afterRender:function() {}
    });
});
```

http://codepen.io/gburton85/pen/XdmMgB

Thank you

Comment: looks like this is fixed in the https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollify/1.0.4/jquery.scrollify.min.js. I was using 1.0.2 before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed latest plugin version https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollify/1.0.4/jquery.scrollify.min.js